# Can tempered chocolate be seeded with a different chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate, tempering

I have unsweetened chocolate, which is stored in seized form (soft, grainy). I use it for chocolate sauces. Is it possible to temper this chocolate by:

1. Sweetening it with white or brown sugar?
2. Then seeding it with Some
   Callebaut 811 dark chocolate chips that I have? Therefore, the
   melted and seeding chocolates are different.

I just recently learned to bake donuts. I tried to glaze it using my regular chocolate sauce recipe made a little thicker. Wasn't good. I revisited tempering chocolate, and thought that having it crystallize over the donut would be perfect and less messy.

Comment: Seems like a tempered chocolate coating would be rather hard for donuts. I think mostly either a ganache, or a simple cocoa/milk/powdered sugar mixture is used.

Comment: The problem with a ganache is that it's sticky, messy, for me at least. Of course it comes down to preference. I'd like to try a nice chocolate crust for a donut.

Comment: There are lots of chocolate glaze recipes that are appropriate for donuts, and you can adjust them to get different levels of firmness. Tempered chocolate is the wrong way to go, though. Tempered chocolate would break away from the donut as soon as you took a bite.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use sugar unless you do not mind having crunchy sugar crystals. There is no way of sweetening chocolate by adding sugar, even powdered sugar, without a conche. I think if the cacao contents are not too dissimilar, you should be fine. I have got away with 70% seeding 85%, but I cannot tell you whether you could get away with any mix. You can also sweeten your 100% by mixing sweet dark chocolate.

I would not use whole chips though, you want it grated. In fact, I would temper the Callebaut first and grate it. Keep a stash of that as seed. I have also routinely tempered dark chocolate without seeding.

Comment: What about powdered sugar? You certainly shouldn't get crystals that way, though I don't know if the starch would upset things.

Comment: Sadly not even powdered sugar with or without starch. I had even tried making my own superfine sugar powder. The result was never smooth like chocolate should be. No crystals as your pointed out, but just a bit sandy/gritty, enough to be annoying and ruin the chocolate completely. The only way I managed to sweeten 100% is by adding semi-sweet dark into the melt before tempering.